# How to pre-set a variable in a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm creating an array of object based on data rows as shown below. While working, it bothers me a bit that I do as assignment to several fields by pulling the same value from a cell in the row. Usually, this thing would be pre-prepared before a loop and then just set multiple times **but** here, I don't obtain the value until **inside** the actual iteration.

```
return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
  .Select(row => new Beep
    {
      Uno = HeavyComputation(row["ID"]),
      Duo = HeavyComputation(row["ID"])
    }).ToList();
```

Can this be addressed in a better way? Something like (just daydreaming here) so?

```
return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
  .Preset("int preComputed = HeavyComputation(row['ID'])"
  .Select(row => new Beep
    {
      Uno = preComputed,
      Duo = preComputed
    }).ToList();
```

Please note that the actual example is a bit more complex and the above code is the minimal exemplification of the issue. I **do** realize that *Uno* and *Duo* here are redundant.   :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this instead:

```
return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
  .Select(row => {
    long preComputed = HeavyComputation(row["ID"]); 
    return new Beep
    {
      Uno = preComputed,
      Duo = preComputed
    };
  });
```

In this case, the parameter of `Select` is a `Func<DataRow, Beep>`. Since a `Func<>` is just a delegate, you can pass an anonymous method to `Select` like in the above example. You could also do this:

```
public Beep TransformToBeep(DataRow dr)
{
    //Do a lot of work here

    return new Beep { ... };
}
```

And then in your `Select` simply write:

```
 return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(TransformToBeep).ToList();
```

Comment: I'll take the liberty to line break your code so it talk to me better. Other than that - perfect! +1

Answer (score 4):

In a query expression, you can use `let` for this:

```
return from DataRow row in table.Rows
       let preComputed = HeavyComputation(row["ID"])
       select new Beep
       {
           // Use row and preComputed here
       };
```

To have the same effect in a non-query-expression, you can use multiple `Select` calls:

```
return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            .Select(row => new { row, preComputed = HeavyComputation(row["ID"]) })
            // Other stuff here if you want
            .Select(pair => new Beep {
                        Uno = pair.preComputed,
                        Duo = pair.preComputed,
                        Trio = pair.Row[...]
                    });
```

If you *only* need `preComputed` in the final `Select` you could just use:

```
return table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            .Select(row => HeavyComputation(row["ID"]))
            .Select(preComputed => new Beep {
                        Uno = preComputed,
                        Duo = preComputed
                    });
```

And if you're happy to have statement lambdas (instead of expression lambdas) then you can use Klaus's approach, of course. Bear in mind that that won't work for things like LINQ to SQL though - it only works with `Enumerable` and statement lambdas can't be converted into expression trees.

Comment: +1 for the SQL-warning. Still, he beat you to it by a few seconds so he gets the greeny checky thingy this time.   :)